# How to retain a value using the select onchange when doing a refresh?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm able to toggle the output the value, but when I hit refresh, the value is reset. I need the value to stay.

```js
function dateFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ClaimContact").value;
  if (x == 0){    
    document.getElementById("answer").value = "Yes"; 
  }
  if (x != 0){
    document.getElementById("answer").value = "No";
  }
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" rules="rows" class="QuestionTable">
  <tr>
    <td #questionstyle# width="10%">Contact?</td>
    <td>
      <select name="ClaimContact" id="ClaimContact" onchange="dateFunction()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">Y</option>
        <option value="1">N</option>
      </select>
    </td> 
    <td #answerstyle# align="right">
      <input type="text" id="answer" readonly style="border: none; text-align: right;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Save it in `localStorage`?

Comment: I tried but wasn’t able to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

are you storing the value anywhere ?? if no than store the selected value in localstorage it will work

Answer (score 0):

Set the value in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage.setItem("name", value);
```

```js
var storedData = localStorage.getItem("storedData");

function dateFunction() {
  var x = storedData | document.getElementById("ClaimContact").value;
  storedData = x;
  if (x == 0){    
    document.getElementById("answer").value = "Yes"; 
  }
  if (x != 0){
    document.getElementById("answer").value = "No";
  }
  localStorage.setItem("storedData", storedData);
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" rules="rows" class="QuestionTable">
  <tr>
    <td #questionstyle# width="10%">Contact?</td>
    <td>
      <select name="ClaimContact" id="ClaimContact" onchange="dateFunction()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">Y</option>
        <option value="1">N</option>
      </select>
    </td> 
    <td #answerstyle# align="right">
      <input type="text" id="answer" readonly style="border: none; text-align: right;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It’s Not working.  When I hit refresh, it’s not staying on the value